# Calling different activity onResume call

Tags: android, onresume

I have 7 different activities and an 8th activity which asks for pass code to continue

Whenever I press home button and access it through the recent apps I want to call the 8th activity to check passcode and then continue to the same activity that I left off

Answer (score 2):

if I come across this situation.
I'll create an Activity, and 7 fragments. I only use onResume 1 time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **startActivityForResult**

in this question you find how to use it.
[How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

You can start the activity you need (8th), to check the passcode is correct and then return to previous activity.

Answer (score 1):

When your application is resumed through recent apps, it is common to use Android's `onResume()` method to get things done.

If you, for instance, want the 8th activity to be started, you could do so there through [Intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) to call the class and check your passcode there. If it's correct, then you can return to activity 7 through Android's `finish()` method which returns to the last activity on the backstack.

You could take a look at implementing this through the Dialogs API as well, which has a [custom implementation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#CustomLayout) for a log in modal.

Comment: Even I thought about the same but then I would have to write the same code in all seven activity which is just redundant . I am looking for a better way but if I get no other solution this will be my final option